# Is it ever correct to say "turn down the building"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, idioms

I'm a non-native speaker of English, and so is my wife. We were talking to a native speaker when at one point, my wife commented, "They should turn down the building." I've never heard of the phrase "turn down" meaning "demolish", so I thought her sentence was unidiomatic. But judging from the nonchalant reaction of the native speaker there, I'm not so sure. What do you say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to say this is:

```
tear down
```

not "turn down".

Your wife must have misheard the original and turned it into "turn down". A common problem that even "native speakers" have!

Actually these have a term themselves:

## Eggcorn

> The term eggcorn was coined by a professor of linguistics, Geoffrey
>   Pullum, in September 2003, in response to an article by Mark Liberman
>   on the website Language Log, a blog for linguists.[4] Liberman
>   discussed the case of a woman who substitutes the phrase egg corn for
>   the word acorn, and argued that the precise phenomenon lacked a name.
>   Pullum suggested using "eggcorn" itself as a label for the class of
>   error. The phenomenon is very similar to the form of wordplay known as
>   the pun, except that, by definition, the speaker (or writer) intends
>   the pun to have some humorous effect on the recipient, whereas one who
>   speaks or writes an eggcorn is unaware of the mistake.

some examples:

> ```
> ex-patriot instead of expatriate
> mating name instead of maiden name
> on the spurt of the moment instead of on the spur of the moment
> preying mantis instead of praying mantis
> ```

Lot's a publications/people/etc have (and do) made (make) the same mistakes - so it shouldn't be anything for your wife to feel too embarrassed about.

Comment: Thanks. It's very likely my wife wanted to say "tear down", but that's not what came out. I didn't want to embarrass her, so I didn't ask to confirm.

Comment: @asif.m updated my comment a little - your wife doesn't need to feel too embarrassed. :D

Comment: @user3306356 What is the difference between an egg corn and a Malapropism, or is it just another name for the same thing? I once heard someone use House of Columns for House of Commons, so should I call these things 'columnisms'. At least Mrs Malaprop has the advantage of age over such new coinages.

Comment: @WS2 I would guess that malapropisms can be "heard" - while egg corns sound the same and are only noticed in writing. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: Nice answer.  One of my recent favorites is from the show. _Modern Family_,... _"don't give me an old tomato"_ meaning _ultimatum_.  For native speakers, a common one I've heard is _old timer's disease_ for _Alzheimer's_, though this one makes sense.

Comment: @asif.m Aside from being torn down, buildings can also be pulled down and taken down.